# Why does Aperture keep forgetting my preference to enable Photo Stream?

Tags: macos, icloud, aperture, photo-stream

I enabled Photo Stream as soon as the feature was available in Aperture 3.2.2, yet sometimes I have to remind the app that I want Photo Stream enabled. I confirm that I want to enable Photo Stream every single time Aperture asks.

*The Mystery of the Disappearing Photo Stream* is further confounding because I can't nail down a pattern. There are days when I open Aperture several times during a day, or maybe with a few days in between, and Photo Stream is working just fine. Other times, Photo Stream disables itself in the same day.

### A couple of notes

1. I do not use iPhoto. The last time I opened iPhoto was to ensure that Photo Stream was disabled there.
2. I know about holding ⌘-opt during launch and have repaired permissions and the database of my Aperture library.
3. Sometimes it remembers my preference between boots, sometimes it forgets.
4. As of January 22, 2012, I am running the latest version of OS X (10.7.2).

I have been searching for an answer periodically for several weeks now and found little more than other people complaining about the same problem in the Apple discussion forums with no answers.

Have you seen this issue? Please help me solve this frustrating mystery!

Answer (score 1):

I think it's simply a bug; see, for instance: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3533813?start=15&tstart=0
for another frustrated user.

Roll on version 3.2.3!